# How to get notified when an image is copied to device via MTP

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-gallery, android-mediascanner

I am writing a Gallery like app.

I want to be notified when an image is copied to device via MTP.

I tried to register a broadcast receiver to listen for media scanner finished action, but it never got called. I tried to both register in AndroidManifest.xml or register in Java code, neither works.

```
<receiver android:name="com.robin.huangwei.omnigif.content.MediaScannerReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

public class MediaScannerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("-----", "Scan finished, new item: " + intent);
    }

}
```

---

or using JAVA code as below

```
mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("-----", "Scan finished, new item: " + intent);
    }
};
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED);
filter.addDataScheme("file");
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

None of the above works.

Whats wrong with my code? I can see every time a new image is copied, it could show in Gallery App. It might be using content observer to watch the media store database, which I don't want to.

I just want to be notified when a new image is added into the device storage via MTP. Since it is added into media store, which must be done by media scanner, why cannot my app capture the broadcast intent? If this is not even correct, I want to know the answer I post as the title.

Comment: "How does Gallery achieve this?" -- probably by using a `ContentResolver` on an appropriate `Uri`, one pointing to where you are pulling your images from.

Comment: OK, maybe, but I don't want to use content observer since I don't want my app to be called so many times due to any change made on media store.

Comment: Why is copying a file by MTP is any different than any other "change made on media store"?

Comment: Since it is added into media store, which must be done by media scanner, why cannot capture the broadcast intent?

Comment: "which must be done by media scanner" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly?

Comment: AFAIK, only media process (which hosts media scanner) maintains the media store database. Gallery app will read the media data base to display the items. So, when I see a newly MTP-copied image showing in Gallery, I know that the media scanner must have just scanned the file. If I am wrong, I want to know the answer to the question of my post.

Comment: "I know that the media scanner must have just scanned the file" -- no. You know that the media *process* must have just scanned the file. This does not need to involve broadcast `Intents`, and I would be stunned if it were implemented that way. For example, the SDK's [`MediaScannerConnection` does not implement it that way](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/java/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.java).

Comment: So you are suggesting to keep a background service always running and maintain a MediaScannerConnection?

Comment: No. `MediaScannerConnection` is for requesting files to be scanned. I mention it only as evidence that you do not need broadcast `Intents` to scan files, and so relying upon broadcast `Intents` as evidence of scanned files is a mistake. I already gave you my recommendation: use a `ContentObserver` (though I typed `ContentResolver` in my original comment, and I apologize for that mistake).

Comment: OK, it seems that is the only choice for me. Thanks for your time.